# How to retrieve values in an array of values from a JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json

Given the following JSON string returned:

```
String s = "{"errorCode":0,"result":"Processed","trips":[{"tripDestination":"Vancouver","tripStartTime":"07:41"},{"tripDestination":"Montreal","tripStartTime":"08:04"}]}";
```

I can easily get errorCode and result with something like:

```
JSONObject jObject;
jObject = new JSONObject(s);

String result = jObject.getString("result");
Log.v("JSON Result", result);
```

But I do I get to tripDestiation values, knowing it's an array of values within the JSON string?

Comment: [Json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) is a simple toolkil for converting Json code to Java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jObject.getJSONArray("trips").getJSONObject(0).getString("tripDestination");
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the `getJSONArray()` method.

See: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)

**Edit**: I would use something like:

```
ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray trips = jObject.getJSONArray("trips");
for (int i = 0; i < trips.length(); i++) {
    destinations.add(trips.getJSONObject(i).getString("tripDestination"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("trips");
```

However consider using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for parsing json. It is lovely:

```
public class Class1 {
    private String erroCode;
    private String Processed;
    private Class2[] trips;
}

class Class2 {
    private String tripDestination;
    private String tripStartTime;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Class1 object = gson.fromJson(s, Class1.class);
```

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this term.

Comment: I was wondering if it used reflection to assign the members' values, since in your example they're declared `private` and there is no constructor and no setters.

Comment: @MattyK It does use reflection. Some people requested properties would be supported as well. You can read more about that in SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203487/why-does-gson-use-fields-and-not-getters-setters