# convert member field map in class into JSON by GSON

Tags: java, json

I have used `GSON` for a while, and I think it is quite useful!
Today I encounter a problem, and I think this maybe refer to some advanced usage of `GSON`.
here is my class definition:

```
class ResolvedID
{
    private String type;
    private HashMap<String,String> data=new HashMap<>(4);

    public String getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }
    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type=type;
    }
    public void put(String K, String V)
    {
        this.data.put(K,V);
    }
}
```

after that I will do the following in some suitable way, here I just write in a simple way:
I will put some data into this hash map:

```
ResolvedID id=new ResolvedID();
id.setType("Bachelor");
id.put("school","Computer Science School");
id.put("major","Software Engineering");
id.put("grade","2009");
```

and I expect GSON might convert it into
`{"type":"Bachelor", "data":{"school":"Computer Science School", "grade":"2009", "major":"Software Engineering"}}`

But unfortunately I only got
`{"type":"Bachelor"}}`

Can anyone give some direction for these kind of member field container to convert into json by `GSON`

Comment: Where does `data` in `data.put("degree","bachelor");` point to? GSON may skip `null`s, so just check if you have assigned the `data` map to the instance of `A` you are trying to serialize.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv  I just simplify the initialization, actually I will assign   `=new HashMap<String,String>();` in member field

Comment: It's confusing now, because your code above might crash with NPE, but you mentioned to obtain a JSON without that field, no crashes. So that's why I assumed that the `data` object may be initialized somewhere else, and _remain not referred_ from the `A` instance.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
A a = new A();
a.data = new HashMap<>();
a.type="teacher";
a.data.put("degree","bachelor");
a.data.put("grade","2013");
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(a));
```

prints

```
{"type":"teacher","data":{"degree":"bachelor","grade":"2013"}}
```

for me.

You must not be initializing `data`. Gson, by default, will not serialize a field if it is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use JavaBeans with nested classes.  Here's an example:

Note:  Obviously you'd build your JsonResponseData class in a different way - I just set prefixed values from within the class for a quick example.

Nested Pojo:

```
public class JsonResponseData {

    private JsonResponse mResponse = new JsonResponse();

    public JsonResponse getJsonResponse(){
        return mResponse;
    }

    public void setJsonResponse(JsonResponse mResponse){
        this.mResponse = mResponse;
    }

    private static class JsonResponse {
        private int part = 1;
        private UserData data = new UserData();
    }

    private static class UserData {
        private User user = new User();

        public User getUser(){
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user){
            this.user = user;
        }
    }

    public static class User {
        private String id = "5";
        private String firstName = "User";
        private String lastName = "Name";

        public String getId(){
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id){
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirstName(){
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName){
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName(){
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName){
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
public class Test {

    private static Gson gson;
    private static JsonResponseData data;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        gson = new Gson();
        data = new JsonResponseData();

        System.out.print(gson.toJson(data));

    }

}
```

Output:

> {"mResponse":{"part":1,"data":{"user":{"id":"5","firstName":"User","lastName":"Name"}}}}

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem at last, it is my problem that I have no `getter` for this hash map, I think `GSON` will use reflect the member field.

If member field is public scoped, `GSON` can get these field and serialize them.
If member field is private scoped, `GSON` will get them by `getter`, hence `GSON` could not serialize those private field that have no `getter`, like my instance above.

```
class ResolvedID
{
    private String type;
    private HashMap<String,String> data=new HashMap<>(4);

    public String getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }
    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type=type;
    }
    //----getter is important for private member field to be reflected by GSON!
    public HashMap getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }
    public void put(String K, String V)
    {
        this.data.put(K,V);
    }
}
```

After adding a getter for my class, it is now successfully executed! 
Now I get more comprehension with `GSON`'s reflection procedure!

Comment: Sorry, but GSON does not use getters or setters. Here is an explanation why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203975/166589