# Retrofit GSON object is null

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm using retrofit in my project, and I've made a GSON object for the response.
But the object only contains nulls.

UserRespomse.java

```
package model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class UserResponse {
    @SerializedName("status") private int mStatus;
    @SerializedName("details") private User mUser;
    @SerializedName("reason") private String mReason;

    public int getStatus() {
        return mStatus;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return mUser;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return mReason;
    }
}
```

UsersService.java

```
@GET("/users/{email}/auth/{password}")
void login(@Path(value="email", encode = false) String email, @Path("password") String password,
        Callback<UserResponse> callback);
```

The JSON returned

```
{"status":200,"details":{"id":1,"email":"orelzion@gmail.com","first_name":"Orel","last_name":"Zion","password":"$2a$10$eHAs0nh0XPsle3ZntjpMYucboMBGcwWpC0mrsNUuBClWXWTUR41w2","created_at":"2014-11-10T08:56:34-05:00","updated_at":"2014-11-10T08:58:01-05:00","facebook_token":null,"facebook_token_updated_at":null,"user_key":"9e38432ec505e1461efe3277ee57bc9025d50270","apps":[],"url":"/users/1"},"reason":""}
```

What could be the reason, or how can I see the GSON logs?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I did but still the same result. BTW I tried parsing it with GSON by myself, still same result. Is there any way to get GSON errors?

Comment: did you get status & reason values or not?

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani Why would setter methods matter?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky because class properties are private and I think you should add setter methods.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani This is not accurate for Retrofit's usage.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the problem is not about Retrofit, it's about Gson and as I read in [Gson design documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-design-document), it doesn't use getter/setter methods. that was my fault.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203487/why-does-gson-use-fields-and-not-getters-setters