# declared custom setter but seems nothing happened with lombok

Tags: java, gson, lombok

I declared a class with annotation `@Data` and declared custom setter.

However, it doesn't happened called setter method.

Here is for build data.

```
    // Build data from json string.
    Type typeOfResultSet = new TypeToken<JsonResult<AntTalkList>>(){}.getType();
        Gson g = new Gson();

    JsonResult<AntTalkList> res = g.fromJson(jsonString, typeOfResultSet);
```

And this is lombok `@Data` anotition added class.

```
@Data
public class TalkInfo {
    private long articleId;
    private long userId;
    private String userName; // this needs custom setter
    private String userType;
    private int last_c_seq ;
    private String title;
    private String question;
    private String dateInfo;
    private int replyCount;
    private String thumbUrl;


    public void setUserName(String userName){ // I want to call this.
        try{
            //This doesn't printed out
            System.out.println("userName");
            this.userName = URLDecoder.decode(userName, "UTF-8");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.userName = userName;
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.
Maybe is there any relations using `Gson` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203487/why-does-gson-use-fields-and-not-getters-setters), GSON doesn't use setters, but sets the fields directly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you Roel.