# What should be my get/set method when property name has dot in it

Tags: json, gson

If my property name has dot in json as shown in below, `payment_details.type` and if I want to retrieve Json value using `Gson`, how and what I will have to do.

```
{
    "statusCode": 422,
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "message": "Bad data received",
    "err_data": {
        "payment_details.type": {
            "location": "body",
            "param": "payment_details.type",
            "msg": "Must be either etransfer or cheque"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am doing this..

```
new Gson().fromJson(response.asString(), MyApiResponse.class).getErr_data().getPayment_details_type().getMsg();
```

It doesn't work for me.. I can't retrieve "msg" value from above json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the field with [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) to indicate the property name for the JSON serialization.

It will be something like:

```java
public class MyApiResponse {

    @SerializedName("err_data")
    private ErrorDetails errorDetails;

    ...
}
```

```java
public class ErrorDetails {

    @SerializedName("payment_details.type")
    private PaymentDetails paymentDetails;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I will take a look and also will try it out.

Comment: So if field name is not same as method name, we should Annotate the field @SerializedName, and if not Annotated then field name should match with the set/get method name? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @OverrockSTAR [Gson uses the fields for serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6203487/1426227) and you can customize the property names with `@SerializedName`.

Comment: OK. but in other case, I didn't have @SerializedName, and was using only getter method to read value and it was working fine.. for e.g. this one - `new Gson().fromJson(response.asString(), MyApiResponse.class).getErr_data().getEmail().getMsg();` - was it working because property name in json was matching with field name?

Comment: @OverrockSTAR _"Was it working because property name in json was matching with field name"_ Yes, you got the idea.

Comment: If I want to use Jackon how would I do it?

Comment: @OverrockSTAR You would use `@JsonProperty` instead.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!